An internal Function Type storing external function
contract FunctionTypeExample {

    // --- Data ---
    function(uint256, uint256) external pure returns (uint256) internal multiplication;

    // --- Init ---
    constructor() {
        multiplication = mul;
    }

    // --- Functions ---
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256) {
        return a * b;
    }
}

Help me understand why solidity is detecting incorrect assignment in constructor but it allows declaration of an internal function type with external function ? And why does not it allow the assignment ? Is it because it follows overriding rule (Can not go from less restrictive to more restrictive)?

The correct assignment would be
multiplication = this.mul;

Because, external function types are address+selector internally (essentially they are pointers to a function).
But, above mentioned is not advised since external functions are not available during contract deployment or constructor. So, above assignment should be moved to a function.
